# Remove hover info text from a plotly object

Tags: r, hover, plotly

I'm creating a `plotly` object in `R`:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, text = ~Species, hoverinfo="text",
             marker = list(size = 10,
                           color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                       width = 2))) %>%
  layout(title = 'Styled Scatter',
         yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE),
         xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE))
```

As you can see it includes `hoverino`.

Then at some point I would like to remove that `hoverinfo` layer.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
style(hoverinfo = 'none')
```

So putting it all together:

```
(p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, text = ~Species, hoverinfo="text",
             marker = list(size = 10,
                           color = 'rgba(255, 182, 193, .9)',
                           line = list(color = 'rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)',
                                       width = 2))) %>%
  layout(title = 'Styled Scatter',
         yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE),
         xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE)) %>% 
  style(hoverinfo = 'none'))
```

Comment: If you use ggplotly to generate the plot, you can edit `hoverinfo` doing `p$data[[1]]$hoverinfo='none'`. I am surprised to see `plot_ly` output has a different structure